# CRM 2013 SP1 - Duplicate call to MessageProcessor start processing message:'Retrieve' for entity:'account'

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have a CRM 2013 SP1 on-premise setup.

This is my scenario. I want to **log every form visit for the Account entity** so I created a **plugin** which hooks onto the **Retrieve** call of the Account enitity.

That's where the problem starts, **I am getting a duplicate entry for each single form view**.

First, I thought I had some error in my plugin, but it's so basic that it's not doing any extra retrieve so that's not the case. It's not a problem with the depth of the context, see from the example trace below.

I did a trace on the CRM server and I can see the two Retrieve calls in the trace log, both seem "legit" calls.

What I have done so far to debug:

- Looked at the IIS access log and checked for multiple form hits, that's not the case.
- Disabled the plugin and made sure no other "external" plugins are hooked into the Account entity.
- Stripped the Account form, removed the Social pane, and actually all other fields from the form, except mandatory 'name'
- Started CRM trace-ing on different organization on the same CRM server and saw the same behavior, that is, Retrieve request being made two times for a single form open action. That org was "clean" if you can say so, has not been modified.

Example output from the tracelog (not complete) which shows the timestamps:

```
[2014-08-15 16:22:11.2] Process: w3wp |Organization:317fc566-698a-e311-93ec-00155d030401 |Thread:   35 |Category: Platform |User: 0574cc0c-364b-4347-93c8-9411e8291c01 |Level: Info | ReqId: 1c905b2e-1e40-4ca3-b743-0ae7ef7b313e | MessageProcessor.Execute  ilOffset = 0x3D
>MessageProcessor start processing message:'Retrieve' for entity:'account' correlationId:17242856-5c45-484c-b79a-0d102988390a depth:1 last updated at: 08/15/2014 16:22:11.

[2014-08-15 16:22:11.2] Process: w3wp |Organization:317fc566-698a-e311-93ec-00155d030401 |Thread:   35 |Category: Platform |User: 0574cc0c-364b-4347-93c8-9411e8291c01 |Level: Info | ReqId: 1c905b2e-1e40-4ca3-b743-0ae7ef7b313e | MessageProcessor.Execute  ilOffset = 0x2DC
>MessageProcessor finish processing message 'Retrieve' for 'account'.

[2014-08-15 16:22:12.8] Process: w3wp |Organization:317fc566-698a-e311-93ec-00155d030401 |Thread:   35 |Category: Platform |User: 0574cc0c-364b-4347-93c8-9411e8291c01 |Level: Info | ReqId: 1c905b2e-1e40-4ca3-b743-0ae7ef7b313e | MessageProcessor.Execute  ilOffset = 0x3D
>MessageProcessor start processing message:'Retrieve' for entity:'account' correlationId:cfe4c47e-31f4-4dfd-8fc9-7ed26187d4b4 depth:1 last updated at: 08/15/2014 16:22:12.

[2014-08-15 16:22:12.9] Process: w3wp |Organization:317fc566-698a-e311-93ec-00155d030401 |Thread:   35 |Category: Platform |User: 0574cc0c-364b-4347-93c8-9411e8291c01 |Level: Info | ReqId: 1c905b2e-1e40-4ca3-b743-0ae7ef7b313e | MessageProcessor.Execute  ilOffset = 0x2DC
>MessageProcessor finish processing message 'Retrieve' for 'account'.
```

I kind of out of ideas and that's where you come to mind, any ideas?

Comment: I would suspect one of two: either CRM itself calls twice retrieve when displaying form (for whatever reason), or you use retrieve call somewhere in your plugin itself.

Comment: I have double-checked the plugin registration on 3 different orgs. to make sure that no other plugins are registered for that entity on that event. So the idea that CRM is calling itself twice for each form load  sounds most likely at the moment.